# React Native: Barcode Scanner does not triggered on iOS [Bug]

Tags: reactjs, react-native, camera, barcode, barcode-scanner

I'm looking for a solution on [react-native-camera](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera) library's barcode scanner bug.
It simply works well on Android but not even triggered the scanner function on iOS.

Here is the **reproducible code**:

```
import { RNCamera } from "react-native-camera";

<RNCamera
   ref={(ref) => {
     this.camera = ref;
   }}
   style={{ flex: 1, width: "100%" }}
   type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
   onGoogleVisionBarcodesDetected={this.barcodeRecognized}
/>

barcodeRecognized = ({ barcodes }) => {
    alert("Barcodes: ", barcodes);
}
```

**Versions**

- iOS: 13.3.1
- react-native-camera: 3.31.0
- react-native: 0.61.5
- react: 16.12.0
- react-navigation:  4.0.10

Also, [Github Issue](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/issues/2888)